# NGINX crashes with 404 not found error

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, nginx

I have ubuntu 14.04 and on the server I have nginx & mysql.
Everything works fine but after 5-10 requests to the API the nginx crashes.
The site has been loading for a long time ends up with 404 not found error.
When I restart the service  `service nginx restart` my site is up again.
I have a strong server with
64GB Ram, 1Gbit Port 33TBMonth,
1TB Disk. 12Cores 24Threads.
I don't understand what's the error and how to solve it.

This is the nginx.conf:
https://pastebin.com/raw/eQtMSKAY

error log nginx:

```
2017/07/30 06:55:43 [error] 18441#0: *6302 connect()
  to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource 
  temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, 
  client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: 4107.150.4.82, request:
  "GET /panel/ajax/user/tools/server?method=getstatus&port=25565 HTTP/1.1", 
  upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", 
  host: "pay2play.co.il", referrer:
  "http://pay2play.co.il/panel/panel?id=15"
2017/07/30 06:55:43 [error] 18441#0: *6302 open() 
  "/usr/share/nginx/html/50x.html" failed (2: No such file 
  or directory), client: 5.29.8.30, server: 107.150.44.82, 
  request: "GET /panel/ajax/user/tools/server?method=getstatus&port=25565 HTTP/1.1", 
  upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", 
  host: "pay2play.co.il", referrer: 
  "http://pay2play.co.il/panel/panel?id=15"
```

Comment: What nginx version are you running? Also can you show us your nginx.conf?

Comment: Debugging this problem will require the NGINX configuration and the server logs of when the problem occurs.

Comment: i running nginx/1.4.6 i cant send the conf its too long

Comment: this is the conf
https://pastebin.com/raw/eQtMSKAY

Comment: some help please?

Comment: Are your php programs timing out? When your API requests succeed, do they come back quickly? It looks like you're using up a pool of php request handlers.

Comment: The answer is in your php fpm log.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you pasted, the actual error is on the PHP side. The 404 is just nginx attempting to render a "nice" error page for the 503/4, contained in 50x.html. While your pasted version doesn't include it, it's likely contained in one of the includes (which are more relevant to the question than the top-level configuration shown here).

I expect there is something like (from the [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) actually):

```
error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
```

Comment: While it the error is to do with the php pool, the nginx log says it is failing to connect to the pool - this is unlikely to be a php code issue

Comment: But it's also not likely an nginx issue. It seems that FPM is running out of resources or is crashing. Nginx simply connects to the available socket.